# Return a list of fibonacci series upto n terms in python

Tags: python

i am struggling to understand the logic as in how to create a python function which takes n as parameter which is the total number of elements to take from the fibonacci series which starts from 0 and then return a list of fibonacci series upto those number of elements.

```
E.g. Input = 3 then Output = [0,1,2]
Input=6 then Output = [0,1,1,2,3,5]
```

Comment: Why does your second list contain 1 twice and the first list doesn't?

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/. This is not a discussion forum; we can only help you with code that you actually show us, or at least an *attempt* to write code. If you are "struggling to understand the logic" then you don't have a question about programming, you have a question about logic. You may find formal tutoring helpful; or you could try searching existing questions on https://cs.stackexchange.com; or you could try taking a real pencil and piece of paper and drawing a flowchart first.

Comment: It wont come as a surprise that this question has been asked before. Please research.

Comment: Recursively: `def fibo(n,a=0,b=1): return [a] if b>n else [a] + fibo(n,b,a+b)`, fibo(6) --> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]

Answer (score 0):

The `rth` term of fibonacci is `r-1th` term + `r-2th` term, where r > 0.
So you can start of with a initial list `[0,1]` and then use a for loop to loop through the natural numbers with the max limit `n` and min limit `1` and then use indexing from the list to get the `r-1th` term and `r-2th` term and then append the `rth` in the list. Heres how I would do it.

```py
intialise the list with elements 0,1
use a for loop here to loop through the natural numbers
get the r-1th from the list
get the r-2th from the list
add both
append the result you got, in the list you initialised
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
ls = [0,1]
for x in range(n):
    if len(ls) < n:
        ls.append(ls[-1] + ls[-2])
print(ls)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You gonna need a **generator** for that.

- Two states will need to be stored.
- Build a list with the size of the sequence.
- Traverse that list, putting at each position the sum of the elements coming before that.
- On the next iteration, the accumulated sum will be stored in the current position.

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

print(list(fib(5)))
>>> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```